# Query planner not using Index scan for WHERE IN condition

Tags: postgresql, index, postgresql-9.6

I have a table `INVENTORY` in PGv9.6.11 and when a run query with `WHERE _column_ IN()`, query planner using `seq scan` even have `index` on that `_column_`

```
CREATE TABLE INVENTORY
(
    process_id bigint,
    load_dttm timestamp(6) without time zone,
    md5_checksum character varying(200)  ,
    storeid character varying(200),
    inventorystatus character varying(200),
    inventorytype character varying(200),
    materialdescription character varying(200),
    serial_nbr character varying(200) ,
    activityid character varying(200) ,
    channel character varying(200) ,
    lastupdateddate timestamp(6) without time zone,
    src_file_date timestamp(6) without time zone,
    run_id character varying(40) "
)
```

I have created indexes in a different ways but none of them are using query planner ,

Reguler `Index`:

```
Create index idx_test1 on INVENTORY (inventorystatus)
```

partial `Index`:

```
Create index idx_test2 on INVENTORY (inventorystatus) where inventorystatus = ANY ('{Received,Returned}')

and 

Create index idx_test3 on INVENTORY (inventorystatus) where inventorystatus in ('Received','Returned')
```

When I run `explain analyze` on the user query:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE select * from  INVENTORY
where INVENTORYSTATUS in ('Received','Returned')
```

And Query planner is:

```
Seq Scan on inventory  as inventory (cost=0..121384.49 rows=2603713 width=157)
Filter: ((inventory.inventorystatus)::text = ANY ('{Received,Returned}'::text[]))
```

Not sure what I'm missing here, any suggestions?

Comment: what is the total number of rows in table INVENTORY?

Comment: 3329176 rows and table is size `650MB`

Comment: A better question would be, what's the number of rows matching `where INVENTORYSTATUS in ('Received','Returned')`

Comment: @mustaccio, it's about 2597609 records.

Comment: [Not about Postgres](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11679/when-is-a-full-table-scan-better-than-index-scan) but the principle is still applicable. I'd even go as far as declaring it a dupe.