# How to avoid cluster index scan?

Tags: query-performance, sql-server-2016, execution-plan, clustered-index

I've a table with a few millions of records. Here's the table structure:

| Column_name | Type | Computed | Length | Prec | Scale | Nullable | TrimTrailingBlanks | FixedLenNullInSource | Collation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Id | int | no | 4 | 10 | 0 | no | (n/a) | (n/a) | NULL |
| A | nvarchar | no | 510 |  |  | yes | (n/a) | (n/a) | French_CI_AS |
| B | nvarchar | no | 128 |  |  | yes | (n/a) | (n/a) | French_CI_AS |
| C | datetime2 | no | 8 | 27 | 7 | yes | (n/a) | (n/a) | NULL |
| D | nvarchar | no | 510 |  |  | yes | (n/a) | (n/a) | French_CI_AS |
| E | datetime2 | no | 8 | 27 | 7 | no | (n/a) | (n/a) | NULL |
| F | nvarchar | no | 1024 |  |  | yes | (n/a) | (n/a) | French_CI_AS |
| G | nvarchar | no | 510 |  |  | yes | (n/a) | (n/a) | French_CI_AS |
| H | nvarchar | no | 510 |  |  | yes | (n/a) | (n/a) | French_CI_AS |
| I | nvarchar | no | 32 |  |  | yes | (n/a) | (n/a) | French_CI_AS |
| J | nvarchar | no | -1 |  |  | no | (n/a) | (n/a) | French_CI_AS |
| K | int | no | 4 | 10 | 0 | yes | (n/a) | (n/a) | NULL |
| L | nvarchar | no | 510 |  |  | yes | (n/a) | (n/a) | French_CI_AS |
| M | nvarchar | no | -1 |  |  | yes | (n/a) | (n/a) | French_CI_AS |
| N | int | no | 4 | 10 | 0 | yes | (n/a) | (n/a) | NULL |
| O | varchar | no | 250 |  |  | yes | no | yes | French_CI_AS |
| P | varchar | no | 250 |  |  | yes | no | yes | French_CI_AS |
| Q | varchar | no | 250 |  |  | yes | no | yes | French_CI_AS |

Here's the query generated by EF :

```
(@p__linq__0 nvarchar(4000),@p__linq__1 nvarchar(4000))SELECT TOP (1) 
    [Project1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Project1].[A] AS [A], [Project1].[B] AS [B], [Project1].[C] AS [C], [Project1].[D] AS [D], 
    [Project1].[E] AS [E], [Project1].[F] AS [F], [Project1].[G] AS [G], [Project1].[H] AS [H], 
    [Project1].[I] AS [I], [Project1].[J] AS [J], [Project1].[K] AS [K], [Project1].[L] AS [L], 
    [Project1].[M] AS [M], [Project1].[N] AS [N], [Project1].[O] AS [O], [Project1].[P] AS [P], 
    [Project1].[S] AS [S]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Extent1].[A] AS [A], [Extent1].[B] AS [B], [Extent1].[C] AS [C], [Extent1].[D] AS [D], 
        [Extent1].[E] AS [E], [Extent1].[F] AS [F], [Extent1].[G] AS [G], [Extent1].[H] AS [H], 
        [Extent1].[I] AS [I], [Extent1].[J] AS [J], [Extent1].[K] AS [K], [Extent1].[L] AS [L], 
        [Extent1].[M] AS [M], [Extent1].[N] AS [N], [Extent1].[O] AS [O], [Extent1].[P] AS [P], 
        [Extent1].[S] AS [S]
        FROM [dbo].[MyTable] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE (@p__linq__0 = [Extent1].[L]) OR ((@p__linq__0 IS NULL) AND ([Extent1].[L] IS NULL)) OR (@p__linq__1 = [Extent1].[L]) OR ((@p__linq__1 IS NULL) AND ([Extent1].[L] IS NULL))
    )  AS [Project1]
    ORDER BY [Project1].[Id] ASC
```

Of course, I've an index on the column `L`.

Almost every query execution is fine, but, sometimes, for a reason I can't explain, it uses the following plan (a Clustered Index Scan on the PK) and ends in a timeout:

[image]

Is there anything I can do to avoid this terrible choice? Am I in the obligation to create a plan guide?

Here's the [problematic plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SJR-rE1ti), and here's the [working one](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HyS1c4yYs);

Here's the C# code:

```
string a = "SomeValue";
string b = "SomeOtherValue"
var entity = service.GetAll()
    .Where(x => a == x.L || b == x.L)
    .OrderBy(x => x.Id)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Please add the plan of both with https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: when @p__linq__1 IS NULL, the last OR condition is not automatically false. If [L].[StudyUID] is not indexed then the whole WHERE cannot be satisfied with an index on L and the query planner chooses the PK scan.

Comment: Add DDL for the index definitions to your question.. An [OPTION(RECOMPILE) query hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40387037/how-to-add-option-recompile-into-entity-framework) might avoid the scan depending on other indexes and parameter values.

Comment: Since this is an EF auto-generated query, it may help to add the C# code for the EF statement, as one solution here may be query tuning by re-writing the code a little.

Comment: @AndreaB. I've made an error on the query anonymization, it's now fixed

Comment: do you have a problem? i'm not convinced that your "working" plan is better. the key lookups are going to be a drag for you at higher cardinalities. sometimes a scan is better https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11679/when-is-a-full-table-scan-better-than-index-scan

Comment: @swasheck Yes, I do have a problem: the working plan is instant, the other one take up to 5 minutes to get results.